# Statistical Inference - Finite Population Correction

Tags: probability, statistics

I am studying for an exam in Quantitative Analysis and I am looking through past exam papers (here's a link the exercise I'm referring to: http://i62.tinypic.com/2cz1nqh.jpg).

I understand all of the questions but I have a slight issue: it asks for standard error for proportion which is √pq/n and then asks what correction factor would apply if n/N > 0.05 (5%). In this case the fpc, or finite population correction factor would apply: √(N-n)/(N-1).

Now, in the next part it asks you to calculate proportion of all employees who would participate in the dental plan. This is 137/200 employees. This means that n/N is greater than 5%. So would I apply the fpc here and how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The estimated standard error would be $\sqrt{\frac{\hat p \cdot (1-\hat p) }{n}}$, if N would be much larger than n. And if $\frac{n}{N} >0.05$, then estimated standard error would be $\sqrt{\frac{\hat p \cdot (1-\hat p) }{n}\cdot \frac{N-n}{N-1}}$. I agree with you.

Ad 2(b)

$\frac{137}{200}=\frac{x}{n}$ and **not** $\frac{n}{N}$. Here you have to assume, that N is much larger than n. N is not given.

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH! What about if n/N < 0.05?

Comment: Then you take $\sqrt{\frac{\hat p \cdot (1-\hat p) }{n}}$ as the estimated standard error. For example: $n=10,N=1000 \Rightarrow \frac{n}{N}=\frac{10}{1000}=0.01$.$\sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N-1}}=\sqrt{\frac{1000-10}{1000-1}}=\sqrt{\frac{990}{999}}=\sqrt{0.\overline{990}}\approx 0.995$. Thus $\sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N-1}}$ is close to 1. This factor can be left out of consideration.

Comment: Thank you very much! Truly appreciate it.

Comment: @Alex You are welcome.